# PHP how to create a function named "do"?

Tags: php, function, reserved-words

I saw a library with a method named "do"

```
public function do
```

totally bugs out parser 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DO, expecting T_STRING in ...

```
//same on call 
$obj->do()
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DO, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in

Gearman Uses a "do" function by the way.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.do.php

Comment: You should put in your question that your purpose is to create a mock object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"do" is a reserved keyword: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

On that same page, in the comments, you see a user mention a way around this. Bear in mind that this method must be used with care:

```
// Now define a __call() method (requires PHP > 5.2.3 to take effect)
public function __call($func, $args)
{
    switch ($func)
    {
        case 'list':
            return $this->ls((isset($args[0]))? $args[0]: null);
        break;
        case 'unset':
            return $this->rm($args[0]);
        break;
        default:
            trigger_error("Call to undefined method ".__CLASS__."::$func()", E_USER_ERROR);
        die ();
    }
```

So you see, you could use a `do` method (or some other reserved word) in any class by using the `__call` overload. Externally, this method would be indistinguishable from a traditionally defined method.

Comment: thanks I know do is a reserved word, and you answered my question.

Answer (score 7):

Its a bad idea to name a function that is a keyword. Its also, maybe even worse name because `do` isn't very descriptive.

*Choose a better name.*

Comment: i don't have a choice . I am creating a dummy class file for Gearman above which has a "do" method. I know its a reserved word, but they made it work I don't know how.

Comment: @Daniel This is a cop-out answer. He asked how it's possible, not if he should or shouldn't.

Comment: @Geocine: Maybe you should explain this in your question.

Comment: Wherever you put a reserved word, It will not work and the parser will whine, and I am using it inside a class. Chris down their answered my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    class MyClass {
        function _do() {
            echo "doing something";
        }

        function __call( $methodName, $arguments ) {
            if( $methodName == 'do' ) {
                $this->_do();
            }
        }
    }

    $myObject = new MyClass();
    $myObject->do();
```

Comment: Any particular utility in posting the same answer I posted 10 minutes ago? :P

Comment: @Chris Didn't notice, I was doing some research to make sure it was the right answer then clicked post.

Answer (score 1):

gearman is a pecl extension, written in c. as such, it is not parsed by the php parser. PHP actually allows you to call a do() method, but wont let you define or use this reserved keyword for anything else when declaring stuff. If you look at the gearman code, you will notice:

```
__PHP_ME_MAPPING(do, gearman_client_do, arginfo_oo_gearman_client_do, 0)
```

so that's how they did it and you cant do it from php itself